# Does overload work with unions of string types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm not sure why this is not accepted by the typescript compiler

```
type Data = 'name' | 'age'

function f(data: 'age'): number;
function f(data: 'name'): string;

function f(data: Data) {
  if (data == 'name') return 'Charlie'
  if (data == 'age') return 8  
}
```

https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDkA7OBbCaoA+6cA5ngFDkBmArhgMbACWA9hlFQBQAmCcAXMTJoAlIIw1sAIwgAnANzU6jVuy69EgzDjxioAZ2CymGEoqUNmbDjz6D4iEVADe5KFCZUotxClTbcUShZCGAaWXY0AGEACzhZABsmCndPbw0kZH9SXWDQ8PYADndyAF8gA

Comment: Adding `any` as a return type seems to do the trick. See [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDkA7OBbCaoA+6cA5ngFDkBmArhgMbACWA9hlFQBQAmCcAXMTJoAlIIw1sAIwgAnANzU6jVuy69EgzDjxioAZ2CymGEoqUNmbDjz6D4iPXAwgoAb3JQoTKlFuIUVG1cUShZCGAaWXY0AGEACzhZABsmCi8fPw0kZCDSXTCIqPYADi9yAF9yIA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function implementation has an implicit return type, so the overloads with an explicit return type aren't able to be mapped onto the original function. If you add an explicit return type to `f()` you overrides will work:

```
type Data = 'name' | 'age'

function f(data: 'age'): number;
function f(data: 'name'): string;

function f(data: Data): string | number | void {
  if (data == 'name') return 'Charlie'
  if (data == 'age') return 8  
}
```

Comment: Isn't `any` enough to avoid having to write _again_ all possible types? Even with `any`, the compiler can infer that only `number` and `string` are available no?

Comment: Sure, but unless you are sure your overload definitions are going to capture every return type, I'd prefer having a list some type surety

Comment: @PaulStenne you're right. The caller will "see" only overloads, the implementation signature won't be listed

Comment: seems to fix the problem indeed, thanks!
Could you explain why when I later call f it produced a compile error even though all types a compatible?

https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDkA7OBbCaoA+6cA5ngFDkBmArhgMbACWA9hlFQBQAmCcAXMTJoAlIIw1sAIwgAnANzU6jVuy69EgzDjxioAZ2CymGEoqUNmbDjz6D4iPROlzCBoyZJuAbiybcoAG9yKCgmKihbRBRUbVxRKFkIYBpZdjQAYQALOFkAGyYKUPDIjSRkWNJdROTU9gAOUPIAX0paS1UoEiiBWD4RIJCbMoGW8iA